# consecutive setdiff in datatable list

Tags: r, list, data.table, set-difference

Using data organised as

```
dtl <- replicate(10,data.table(id=sample(letters,10),val=sample(10)), simplify=F)
lapply(dtl, function(x){setkey(x,'id')})
```

I need to extract a list of datatables that contain the rows in dtl[[n+1]]] with **id** not present in dtl[[n]]. I assume it would be something like

```
dtl2 <- list(setdiff(dtl[[1]][['id']],dtl[[2]][['id']]),setdiff(dtl[[2]][['id']],dtl[[3]][['id']]...)
```

Please notice that, while the setdiff should only take the **id** column into account, I expect the result to contain all columns from each datatable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will do it for you:

```
mapply(setdiff, head(dtl, -1), tail(dtl, -1), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

**Edit**: with your new expected output, I would still use `mapply` as above, but with one of the following two changes:

1. replace `setdiff` with `function(x,y)setdiff(x$id, y$id)`
2. replace `dtl` with `ids <- lapply(dtl, "[", "id")`

**Edit2:**: you've changed your expected output again by adding a plain English description that does not match the code you had provided... I *think* you are now looking for this:

```
mapply(function(x,y)y[setdiff(y$id, x$id), ],
       head(dtl, -1), tail(dtl, -1), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Comment: The tail/head solution is very ingenious. But after running this statement I still get identical IDs in consecutive data.tables :(

Comment: @dmvianna Sounds like you may be confused about what `setdiff` does (on a data table with multiple columns), and need to be more specific about your desired output.

Comment: Hmm. @dmvianna, I am fairly certain my output is identical to your expected `dtl2` (as currently defined in your question). Can you review?

Comment: @joran, you two were right, I did not express myself clearly. I changed the result statement to better describe what I'm seeking.

Comment: @dmvianna You just need to replace `setdiff` with a custom function that basically does this: `setdiff(dtl[[1]][['id']],dtl[[2]][['id']])`. I'm sure flodel will edit accordingly...

Comment: Your solution returns the IDs (Thanks!), and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615432/subset-in-parallel-using-a-list-of-dataframes-and-a-list-of-vectors) returns the rows I'm looking for. :7D